# Match any of multiple strings containing spaces

Tags: regex

I have a list of customer names which could have one or more words. I need an expression that will match any of these names EXACTLY. So for "ABC Gas" and "XYZ Corp", I want only exact matches, but not any string with "Gas" or "Corp".

Something like (ABC Gas|YZY Corp|...|...) but matching only exactly, not partially.

I'm a regex noob, so have mercy if the solution is supremely easy!

Comment: Just as in the linked answer: `^(ABC Gas|YZY Corp|...|...)$`. In Ruby, use `\A(ABC Gas|YZY Corp|...|...)\z`.

Comment: Thank you, Wiktor! Believe it or not, I actually searched Google long & hard before posting the question.